# GetProperty BindingFlags.IgnoreCase wont work without public and Instance in c#

Tags: c#, reflection

```
 Type t = typeof(T);
  t.GetProperty("Company")
```

If i write the below code it will give null

```
    Type t = typeof(T);
t.GetProperty("company", BindingFlags.IgnoreCase)
```

In the mean time if i write this works fine.Why is that so ?

```
Type t = typeof(T);
t.GetProperty("company", BindingFlags.IgnoreCase|BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The overload which *doesn't* take `BindingFlags` effectively defaults to `BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance`. That's why it finds it in your first snippet.

If you *do* specify a `BindingFlags`, you have to specify *all* the relevant flags - which includes flags to say whether you want to see public members, whether you want to see non-public members, whether you want to see instance members, and whether you want to see static members.

When you *just* specify `BindingFlags.IgnoreCase`, you haven't said you want to see any of those, so it won't find anything.

Answer (score 7):

By design [Type.GetProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy0d4103.aspx) requires that you specify at least Static or Instance:

> •You must specify either BindingFlags.Instance or BindingFlags.Static in order to get a return.

Answer (score 5):

[`GetProperty(string name)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy.aspx) **searches for the public property with the specified name** (according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy.aspx)) but [`GetProperty(string, BindingFlags)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy0d4103.aspx) **searches for the specified property, using the specified binding constraints** exactly as you specified.

When you say `BindingFlags.IgnoreCase`, it just applies that `BindingFlag`, and nothing else. According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy0d4103.aspx), you must specify either `BindingFlags.Instance` or `BindingFlags.Static` in order to get a return.